# configtxgen is not finding organization with -printOrg option

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

fabric & fabric-ca version

```
2.4.7 1.5.5
```

In /root/demo/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml

```
    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"
```

run

> configtxgen -printOrg Org1

root@BCN1N108450:~/demo/fabric-samples# export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/test-network/configtx/
root@BCN1N108450:~/demo/fabric-samples# configtxgen -printOrg Org1
2022-12-02 14:22:14.071 CET 0001 INFO [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> Loading configuration
2022-12-02 14:22:14.086 CET 0002 INFO [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> orderer type: etcdraft
2022-12-02 14:22:14.086 CET 0003 INFO [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:16777216
2022-12-02 14:22:14.086 CET 0004 INFO [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] LoadTopLevel -> Loaded configuration: /root/demo/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml
**2022-12-02 14:22:14.086 CET 0005 FATA [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> Error on printOrg: organization Org1 not found**
root@BCN1N108450:~/demo/fabric-samples#

I keep finding errors. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
- &Org1
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org1MSP

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org1MSP

    MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
    #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"
```

The Org1 is a reference name of the configuration section related to the definition of the organization, while running `confitxgen` you need to reference it by actual organization ID, which in your case is `Org1MSP`:

```
configtxgen -printOrg Org1MSP
```